# Center list in div (for navigation bar)

Tags: html, css

Going off of the note at the top of this tutorial (http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/), I tried to center a list of two links in the page, but it is centering only the first list item, not the entire list.

```
li{
    font-family: Futura, Arvo, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul{
    text-align: center;
}

div#nav-list {

    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #E8E8E8;
}
```

"nav-list" is the container for the navigation bar, shown in the picture colored grey.

Here is the issue- you can see that "about" is centered, but not the entire list. 
[image]

Thanks in advance!
Edit: Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="center_content">
    <h1 id="page-heading">Title</h1>
    <hr id="first-rule"></hr>
    <div id="nav-list">
        <ul>
            <li>about</li> <li>work</li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
    <p>Here is a paragraph. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your full html and css for navigation. Then it will more easier to solve.

Comment: Updated with more code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aTj4U/ try this fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the list padding. By default, list have a `40px` padding-left. Try to use `ul{ padding:0; }`

Comment: Hmm, this moves it slightly in the right direction but it's still not centered. I also tried adding margin:0 but that didn't do anything.

Comment: If there's no other definition that overwrites your styles, settings for the ul `{ margin:0 auto; text-align:center; padding:0;}` and for li `{ display:inline-block;}` will be your answer. Set these styles and check again, if they still not working, check for overwriting rules

Comment: Thank you! I had a text-indent set on a div further up in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Try apply these styles :

```
ul { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 170px; /*as per your need*/
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. Still aligning to the first list item. Also shouldn't the inline-block be applied to the list item, not the list itself?

Answer (score 0):

Hows this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/6UnNs/

**CSS**

```
li {
    font-family: Futura, Arvo, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    background:red;
    width: 25%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
ul li:first-child {

    background:#ccc;
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 0 -40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>TITLE</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Just play with settings I added some color so you can see

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

```
div ul li{float:left;list-style:none;margin:0 10px}
div ul{display: inline-block;margin: 0 auto;}
div{text-align:center}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhRxr/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1) Set `text-align: center;` on the nav-list element

2) Set d`isplay: inline-block` on the list

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x4Ay2/1/)**

```
li {
    font-family: Futura, Arvo, sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
ul{

    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
}

div#nav-list {

    text-align: center;
    background: #E8E8E8;
}
```